# How to edit jquery customSelect tag

Tags: jquery

I have a select tag a normal select tag and which is created using custom select box. Now I want to add and remove option from it onchange but nothing is working I believe this is because select tag is created using custom select box.

Please assist me as how to edit select tag on change created using custom select tag.

**Html code**

```
<div class="text" style="width: 300px;">   <span align='center' id='text' style='display:none'></span>
<select  id="secretQ" name="secretQ" onchange="checkCustom(this,5)" style="width:300px;">
    <option> </option>
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >2</option>
    <option value="4" >2</option>
</select>
```

**code to remove and add option**

```
// remove element
$("#secretQ" option[value == "+ques+"]").remove();

// add element
$("#secretQ").append("<option value="+oldValue+">"+oldValue+"</option>");
```

But the above code is not working. I found on the net some thing like trigger render which will reload the customSelect tag

Comment: It's not quite clear what specifically you are intending to do. Just be able to add/remove options? Or execute some functionality on change?

Comment: @creimers I am having a select tag which is normal html tag but the same is being displayed using jquery customSelect. But I want to add/ remove from select onchange but the append and remove code is not working. Instead of jquery customSelect if I use simple html code the add/remove is working. Thanks..

Comment: It seems weird to me that you want to add/remove onchange.

Comment: @creimers my requirement is there 4 select tag having same option if any option is selected in any tag then I have to remove that option from rest of the select.

Comment: I updated my answer. There's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H987d/) awaiting you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an option to your select like so:

```
$('#secretQ').append('<option value="3">three</option>');
```

And remove an option like so:

```
$('#secretQ').find("option[value=3]").remove();
```

**EDIT**

Now that you specified what you *really* want, try this:

**HTML**

```
<select class="mySelect" id="select_1" onchange="disableSelected(this)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">select an option...</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="1">one</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="2">two</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="3">three</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select class="mySelect" id="select_2" onchange="disableSelected(this)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">select an option...</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="1">one</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="2">two</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="3">three</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="4">four</option>
 </select>

<select class="mySelect" id="select_3" onchange="disableSelected(this)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">select an option...</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="1">one</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="2">two</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="3">three</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select class="mySelect" id="select_4" onchange="disableSelected(this)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">select an option...</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="1">one</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="2">two</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="3">three</option>
    <option class="select_option" value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function disableSelected(selector) {
    var toBeDisabled = selector.value;
    selectedOptions = [];

    $.each($('.mySelect'), function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($(this).children('.select_option'), function () {
        if (id != selector.id && $(this).context.value == toBeDisabled) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        };

        if ($(this).context.selected) {
            selectedOptions.push($(this).context.value);    
        };
    });
});
enableUnselected(selectedOptions);
}

function enableUnselected (selectedOptions) {
    $.each($('.select_option'), function () {
        if( $.inArray($(this).context.value, selectedOptions) == -1) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: will implement above code and post the comment. Thanks